# Как мне открыть новую форму удовлетворяющее условию БД?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Хочу авторизоваться под 3 роли:

1. Мастер
2. Админ
3. Менеджер

Ну и не долго думая создал кучу RadioButton и задал им значения от 1...3, т.к в БД MySQL прописано таблица с Authorized и в ней есть 4 таблицы:

- ID,
- Login,
- Password,
- Status(ну в каком то плане привилегия).

Собственно в Status разбит на интовые значение от 1...3, где:

1. это АДМИН
2. это Мастер
3. это Менеджер

В итоге перепробовав все я пришел к тому что не могу никак открыть новую форму 2(Главную) чтобы это удовлетворяло условию от 1...3 RadioButton'ов. То есть он заходит, при любом выбор RadioButton...
Вот мой код:

```csharp
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int status1;
        int status2;
        int status3;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string loginUSER = textBox1.Text;
            string passUSER = textBox2.Text;

            DB database = new DB();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `authorized` WHERE `Login` = @uL AND `Password` = @uP", database.getCon());
            command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUSER;
            command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUSER;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);

            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("да");
                userROLE();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("нет");
            }
        }
        private void checkedRadioButton()
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                status1 = 1;
            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                status2 = 2;
            }
            if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
            {
                status3 = 3;
            }
        }
        private void userROLE()
        {
                checkedRadioButton();
            if (status1 == 1)
            {
                DB database1 = new DB();
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
                MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `authorized` WHERE `Status`=@uS", database1.getCon());
                command1.Parameters.Add("@uS", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = status1;
                adapter1.SelectCommand = command1;
                adapter1.Fill(table1);
                if (table1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                    f2.Show();
                    Hide();
                }
            }
                if (status2 == 2)
                {
                    DB database2 = new DB();
                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                    DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
                    MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `authorized` WHERE `Status`=@uS", database2.getCon());
                    command2.Parameters.Add("@uS", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = status2;
                    adapter2.SelectCommand = command2;
                    adapter2.Fill(table2);
                    if (table2.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                        f2.Show();
                        Hide();
                    }
                }
                if (status3 == 3)
                {
                    DB database3 = new DB();
                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter3 = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                    DataTable table3 = new DataTable();
                    MySqlCommand command3 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `authorized` WHERE `Status`=@uS", database3.getCon());
                    command3.Parameters.Add("@uS", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = status3;
                    adapter3.SelectCommand = command3;
                    adapter3.Fill(table3);
                    if (table3.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                        f2.Show();
                        Hide();
                    }
                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В каждом из 3 вариантов вы пишите Form2 f2 = new Form2(); f2.Show();  так почему вас удивляет, что каждый раз открывается одна и та же форма?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что для начала Ваша форма должна знать кто инициализирует ее и в зависимости от внедряемого поля/свойства форма меняет поведение

```
var f2 = new Form2(); // внедрять можно и через конструктор, для этого собственно создаётся нужный конструктор
f2.User a можно и через свойство которое и будет определять её поведение 
f2.Show();
Hide();
```

а можно опредлелять отдельные формы для отдельных ролей, если формы кардинально отличаются

```
var f2 = new ManagerForm();
f2. введите тут какое нибудь свойство котороеи будет определять её поведение 
f2.Show();
Hide();

var f2 = new AdminForm();
f2. введите тут какое нибудь свойство котороеи будет определять её поведение 
f2.Show();
Hide();
```

.....

Comment: я имел ввиду не добавлять кучу форм, у меня вопрос в другом. Почему не выполняется условие MySQL кода???  То есть она как бы должен сравнивать status1 со Status в БД, а он это будто бы не делает и всегда нажимая на любую кнопку RadioButton заходит в форму2